# I want to increase the frequency of Particles Being Emitted, currently there is a gap before every emission (Screen shot attached)

Tags: particles

[image]

So I was trying to create a Comet emitting sparks, I just started the emissions but as the Comet animates through a Path, I noticed the emission of particles is at a constant frequency which creates these gaps as shared on the Screen shot. How can I reduce or break this Gap?

Comment: increase number of the particles wont help?

Comment: Are you using a particle system to do this?  In that case, have you unchecked _Even Distribution_ in the particle system _Source_ settings?

Comment: Thanks MikoCG and Marty Fouts for your replies, The Particle amount I have raised from 10000 to 200000 and I have also unchecked Even Distribution but the results are still the same

Comment: Here someone proposes a solution with particle texture but I don't know how it works: https://blenderartists.org/t/is-uneven-distribution-of-particles-over-time-possible/697991/5